# Set dependent select box without its value

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core

I'm developing a page using ASP.net and in one of the pages I have a select list that depends on another. However, the options of the dependent list do not have only the value of the other select list, they also have its own id. I know it's a terrible solution, I'll change that soon, but thats what I need right now. Code as follows.

Setting the list:

```
listaversao = _context.Versao.Select(v => new SelectListItem
 {
   Value = v.idLinguagem.ToString() +"*" +v.idVersao.ToString(),
   Text = v.nmVersao
  });
```

Now the javascript:

```
$('#lingua').change(function () {
    $('#versa').hide();
    var n = $("#versa option").split("*");
    n = $n[0]; 
    $('#street option[value="' + n + '"]').show();
    // add this code to select 1'st of streets automaticaly 
    // when city changed
    if ($('#street option[value="' + n + '"]').length) {
        $('#street option[value="' + n + '"]').first().prop('selected', true);
    }
    // in case if there's no corresponding street: 
    // reset select element
    else {
        $('#versa').val('');
    };
})
```

And the html:

```
<div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Scripts.idLinguagem" class="control-label"></label>
    <br />
    <select id="lingua" asp-for="linguagem" asp-items="Model.listaling">      </select>
  </div>
  <div>
     <div class="form-group">
         <label class="control-label">Versão Disponível</label>
         <br />
         <select id="versa" onclick="mostrarv()" multiple="multiple" asp-for="selecaover" asp-items="Model.listaversao"></select>
         <br />
      </div>
   </div>
```

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems you want to get the selected option value of the `versa` dropdownlist and split to get its `idLinguagem` , since `versa` is multi-select dropdownlist , so just modify your javascript to :

```
$('#lingua').change(function () {
  $('#versa').hide();

  $.each($("#versa").val(), function (index, value) {
      var n = value.split("*")[0]

      ....//your other operations 
  });

})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! With this function, how can I add on the versa dropdownlist only the ones with the same id than the other  list?